# Mysql Transfer data between tables with different unique id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table -

```
CREATE TABLE ccfarch 
( id tinyint(7) AUTO_INCREMENT,
 jobno varchar(15),
 partno varchar(40),
 descr varchar(250),
 serno varchar(200),
 batno varchar(200),
 acreg varchar(30),
 suppname varchar(100),
 orderqty int,
 delqty int,
 stockqty int,
 reorderqty int,
 orddate date,
 deldate date,
 bcost decimal(5,2),
 scost decimal(5,2),
 totcost decimal(5,2),
 expdate date,
 location varchar(30),
 notes text,
 svarchar1 varchar(200),
 svrchar2 varchar(200),
 sint1 int,
 sint2 int,
 sdate date,
 senum1 enum('y','n') DEFAULT 'n',
 senum2 enum('y','n') DEFAULT 'n',

 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 UNIQUE id (id));
```

I want transfer records into a similar table but with a new unique id (ida) so that previous unique (id) is no longer the unique id in the second table - I have added a new unique id to the second table(ida)

I use the following query to move the records but it won't work and I can't understand why?

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO ccfarch2 SELECT * FROM ccfarch WHERE jobno = '$jobno'")

CREATE TABLE ccfarch2 
( ida tinyint(7) AUTO_INCREMENT,
 id tinyint(7),
 jobno varchar(15),
 partno varchar(40),
 descr varchar(250),
 serno varchar(200),
 batno varchar(200),
 acreg varchar(30),
 suppname varchar(100),
 orderqty int,
 delqty int,
 stockqty int,
 reorderqty int,
 orddate date,
 deldate date,
 bcost decimal(5,2),
 scost decimal(5,2),
 totcost decimal(5,2),
 expdate date,
 location varchar(30),
 notes text,
 svarchar1 varchar(200),
 svrchar2 varchar(200),
 sint1 int,
 sint2 int,
 sdate date,
 senum1 enum('y','n') DEFAULT 'n',
 senum2 enum('y','n') DEFAULT 'n',

 PRIMARY KEY (ida),
 UNIQUE id (ida));
```

Comment: so what is your problem? and what is your error text?!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't `SELECT *` from the table with less fields unless you specify the fields in `INSERT INTO (....)`

So, to make it easier you could (assuming only the first field is different):

```
INSERT INTO ccfarch2 SELECT NULL, t.* FROM ccfarch t WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a miss match in the number of columns, try this it should work

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ccfarch2(id , jobno, partno, descr, serno, batno, acreg, suppname, orderqty, delqty, stockqty, reorderqty, orddate, deldate, bcost, scost, totcost, expdate, location, notes, svarchar1, svrchar2, sint1 , sint2, sdate, senum1, senum2 )
 SELECT * FROM ccfarch WHERE jobno = '$jobno'")
```

Comment: Still not working so I simplified the query - mysql_query("INSERT INTO ccfarch2(id, jobno, partno, descr) SELECT(id, jobno, partno, descr)  FROM ccfarch WHERE jobno = '$jobno'") Only seems to work if both tables are identical?

Comment: don't know what is the error you are getting ..  if it is possible echo the query string and execute it in the database.

Comment: Solved it - no parenthesis after SELECT, removed these and it works fine, Doh! help appreciated as always